# Transparent image planes near each other are black

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

i am making a plant and i have run into some problems. I have here some grass blade texture:

[image]

And since i want the whole pot to be filled with grass blades, i duplicated them until it filled the whole pot:

[image]

but as you can see, some of the image planes look like they have a black background:

[image]

Here is my node setup:

[image]

Comment: increase transparency bounces

Answer (score 3):

Go to the *Light Paths* panel in the Render tab and increase the transparent bounces (you'll probably be fine just setting them to the max value of 1024). Basically Blender is terminating the light rays after they go through a certain number of transparent objects.

Comment: Thanks a ton man, it worked...i watched a Blender guru tutorial on speeding up cycles and he said to reduce transparency bounces...that was the problem