# black boxes in render mode

Tags: rendering

[image]

In the render preview or when i render the scene this black boxes show up.
they look different and change form from from every angle. All objects are imported  as images as planes. 
some produce these black boxes, some do not.
please help, thanks.

Comment: Please show your uv map for all/~all items which have a texture map.

Comment: ![Valid XHTML]( https://imgur.com/a/3wxXwFp).

Comment: you mean this? when i activate this object the black box gets bigger

Comment: Can you upload your blend file?

Comment: Also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42023/transparent-textured-planes-produce-black-artifacts and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99647/transparent-image-planes-near-each-other-are-black/99650#99650